# Angular call directive during init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a directive that will add a group to a UI Bootstrap accordion when an element is clicked:

```
eApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                var accordion = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('panel-group')[0]);
                var tag = '<div accordion-group> ... </div>';
                var newGroup = $compile(tag)(scope);
                accordion.append(newGroup);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now sometimes based on user preferences I want these accordion groups to be automatically displayed, instead of requiring the user to click the element.  Is there a way to trigger this directive when my app is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured it out.  Instead of binding to the click like this:

```
element.bind('click', function (e) {
```

I do a watch on a scope variable like this:

```
scope.$watch('node.checked', function (newValue, oldValue) {
```

Now if node.checked is true then I display the new group.